# Good place to start for client / server network programming?

Tags: c++, networking

I have lots of experience with C++, (native) but I have never really ventured into network programming (example: games, chat software, or software that gets a file from a Web Site. )Where would be a good place to start for this? Preferably tutorials which are cross platform, and possibly some sort of project (not just theory). I ave found hundreds of great tutorials for C++, but few for Network programming) (which is not necessarily web programming).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046404/getting-started-with-client-server-networking/4092277#4092277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html) is a fantastic cross-platform C++ networking library. The [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) and [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) are straightforward.

There's also plenty of help on stackoverflow in the [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio) tag

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a simple HTTP server, which will lead you to HTTP protocol, file operations, multi-thread/event handling and etc. Or a distributed file system/cache system and etc. A lot of fun in it.